# Edit Hover menu Google Charts

Tags: javascript

in google charts I am trying to make a combo chart. I am importing the file in my javascript, and all the references on tool tips include data that is created inside the drawChart() function. Any references would be great. How can I change the view of the menu to look like the following image..

[Change Chart menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsVoW.png)

my table looks like this:

```
.....|ColB|ColB|
Date |ColA|ColC|
2007 |12  |13  |
2009 |14  |16  |
```

I have gotten the column chart to work, I am at a loss to change the menu options.